# How do I get wireless working on an Asus X552VL?

Tags: wireless, atheros

I have a problem with my Wireless on my laptop. When i did rfkill list:

```
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

itko@Mitko:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

mitko@Mitko:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2c97]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
mitko@Mitko:~$ lsmod | grep -e ath9k -e asus
asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
ath9k                 164164  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              626557  1 ath9k
cfg80211              484040  4 wl,ath,ath9k,mac80211
wmi                    19177  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  19476  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi
```

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: Please see the answer on the link I provided.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the hardware switch?

Comment: I found something when i start the laptop i don't have Wi-Fi i pressed fn + f2 the wireless switch and nothing but when i put it in sleep fn + f1 and when i turn it on i have wi fi

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to my problem. It was the module that wasn't loaded.

```
lsmod | grep asus
```

If so, please try a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
exit
```

Then i rebooted my system and everything was fine.